# ‘calibrateCamera’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: opencv, camera

I tried to get the camera matrix using calibrateCamera() function:

> double x= calibrateCamera(objectPoints,imagePoints,imageSize,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs,rvecs,tvecs,0);

and i got

> ‘calibrateCamera’ was not declared in this scope

i didn't forgot to write

> using namespace cv;

what can it be?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it:

i was missing the header:

> #include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

thanks anyway